Binary Search in Java personalized implementation not working properly
Why is my code not working though I've tried dry running it 1000 times, but still I'm not able to find my doubt, maybe I'm short of the knowledge which will help me find the mistake, can anybody help me with this?
package _08_Arrays;

public class _04_Binary_Search {
    

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = { 5, 3, 2, 4, 1 };
    int target = 2;
    SortArray(arr);
    System.out.print(BinarySearch(arr, target));
}

public static int BinarySearch(int[] arr, int target) {
    int s = 0; // I took int s=arr[0] which will provide inconvenience in case if I want do s++
                // or s--, it will increase the value of the element in the array by one.
    int n = arr.length;
    int e = n - 1;
    for(;s<=e;) {
        int mid=(s+e)/2;
        if(arr[mid]>target) {
            e=mid-1;
        } else if(arr[mid]<target) {
            s=mid+1;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void SortArray(int[] arr) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int idx=-1;
    int sort=0;
    for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++) {
        int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i=sort;i<arr.length;i++) {
            if(arr[i]<min) {
                min=arr[i];
                idx=i;
            }
        }
        int temp=arr[sort];
        arr[sort]=min;
        arr[idx]=temp;
        sort++;
        }
}

}
I tried to get the index of the element which I tend to pass in the target element, but I'm getting different index of the element in the array which is different from the actual index of elements of the array.

I tried running your code and didn't see any problems.

There’s no point in prepending a sort operation to the Binary Search implementation you want to test. The search will return an index to the sorted array, so use a sorted array in the first place. The code as posted, produces index one, not zero, which is the expected index, as the previous commenter already said.

dsa is about something else. Removed tag.

"I'm getting 0 always ": I cannot reproduce that. Running your code I get 1 as output. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Please see carefully, run for different values of targets, for target as 1 in array { 5, 3, 2, 4, 1 }, it is giving 0 as the index in the array, for target as 4 in array { 5, 3, 2, 4, 1 }, it is giving 3 as the index in the array, for target as 2 in array { 5, 3, 2, 4, 1 }, it is giving 1, etc. which are obviously not the desirable output.

Holger , I can use the Arrays.sort function but I don't want to use that, instead I want to create my own implementation of sorting the array by creating my own function for it. Please see in my code, I have used SortArray(int[] arr) function and I've called it before printing the BinarySearch(arr, target) function because an array is passed by reference in a function.

trincot I think Binary Search is a part of learning DSA (Data Structures and Algorithms), without binary search the questions of DSA can't be solved because Binary search is a type of searching technique, in this case for an array.
